# Displaying an Array of type Double on UILabel in Xcode

Tags: swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

I am trying to make a basic shopping cart app where you can add an item to your cart, store the cost of the item in an array and then have the array displayed when you click "Receipt". However, every time I click "Receipt" on my app, the simulator crashes and displays

`"Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

beside my line of code that reads "allItems += item". If anyone has any ideas as to how I can my array of numbers displayed in a UILabel using a for in loop, please let me know. I will post source code below. Thanks in advance

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var priceOfApple = 1.75
var cart = [Double]()
var total = 0.00

@IBOutlet weak var appName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Balance: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Instructions: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var redApple: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var appleInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addToCart: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemsPurchased: UILabel!


@IBAction func selectedApple(sender: AnyObject) {

    Instructions.hidden = true
    appleInfo.hidden = false
    addToCart.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func purchaseApple(sender: AnyObject) {

    cart.append(priceOfApple)
    total += priceOfApple
    Balance.text = "Balance : \(total)"
    Instructions.hidden = false
    appleInfo.hidden = true
    addToCart.hidden = true


}

@IBAction func viewReceipt(sender: AnyObject) {

    redApple.hidden = true
    Instructions.hidden = true
    itemsPurchased.hidden = false

    for item in cart {

        var allItems = Double(itemsPurchased.text!)!
        allItems += item
        allItems = Double(itemsPurchased.text!)!
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The body of the `item in cart` loop is very confusing. In each iteration you are creating a new variable `allItems` with the contents of a label, then you're adding `item` and finally you're setting the variable back to the contents of the label. Apart from that confusion either `itemsPurchased.text` is `nil` or the text cannot be represented by a `Double`.

Comment: I am creating variable allItems in each iteration because I want all items in the array to be displayed. Is there a better way I could do such?

Comment: There are two serious problems with this code. The worse is that the variable is not visible outside the scope of the loop and you are permanently overwriting previous values with new ones. You should create the variable **before** the repeat loop. Paste the code in a Playground and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you should do:

First, create a variable outside the for-loop, 
then inside the loop that variable will start storing every value in the array separated by " ". Once It is done, you can display its value in the Label.

```
  var itemsInCart = ""

    for items in cart{

        itemsInCart += String(items) + " "
    }

    itemsPurchased.text = itemsInCart
```

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: Yes, this helped tremendously! Thank you very much for your help. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and safer way to do it:

```
let result = cart.flatMap { Double(itemsPurchased.text ?? String()) }.reduce(0: combine: +)
```

Doing that, you shouldn't get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION anymore, but you should still check if is the text convertible to a Double.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I am trying to get a better understanding of using for-in loops and am looking for an answer using a for-in loop.